# Parse "Bring our own login" installationId mismatch for created Session

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I have a self-hosted parse server (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server), I have some cloud code on my parse server to register the user because i'm using a custom authentification method. (has described here: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/bring-your-own-login/).

The flow works that way:

- Start custom login process on client (ios)
- Call a custom "registerUser" function in my cloud code to finish auth process
- In the cloud code :

  - Validate my user (part of my custom authentification)
  - Sign in the user to parse (if it does not exists)
  - Login the user to parse
  - Send the login session token back to the client
- Back in my client, "become" the user with the session token

**My problem**

I have a valid Session object for my user, which match the session token returned to the client. BUT, the installationID of the session does not match the Installation object of my user.

This is a problem because when I try to send a push notification to a specific user, I find the session, but can't find any installation corresponding to that session.

The installationID from the session comes from the cloud code, or parse server itself instead of coming from the user device.

**Hypothesis**

Either I am missing a step in the cloud code to associate the session (and thus user session token) to the user installation.

Or maybe there is a bug with the installationID in the session which does not correspond to any Installation in my database. I think this installationID comes from the parse server because it changes everytime I restart the server and become the session is created from the cloud code (login is done from the cloud code).

Can someone understand the problem and have a fix or a workaround for that ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you save the user object in your installation ?

Comment: @RanHassid No because you can loggin and logout in the app (multiuser app) and it creates only one installation...